# bad operand types for binary %, first type java.lang.Object second type int (java)

Tags: java

Okay, sorry for being unclear, here's my full code.

I'm trying to create a for loop (close to the bottom) to remove all elements at all odd indices in the vector list. On the line of code that says, 'if (vector.get(i) % 2 == 1);' 
I'm getting the error 'bad operand types for binary %, first type java.lang.Object second type int' in NetBeans. I couldn't find any questions that dealt with the '%' operand specifically. Thank you.

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.Vector;



 public class Lab1 
 {
    public static void test(String[] args) 
 {


    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    int primitiveInt = 241;
    Integer wrapperInt = new Integer(1234);
    String str = "<Your Name>";
    vector.add(primitiveInt);
    vector.add(wrapperInt);
    vector.add(str);
    vector.add(2, new Integer(2138));
    System.out.println("The elements of vector: " + vector); System.out.println("The size of vector is: " 
    + vector.size());
    System.out.println("The elements at position 2 is: " 
    + vector.elementAt(2));
    System.out.println("The first element of vector is: " 
    + vector.firstElement());
    System.out.println("The last element of vector is: " 
    + vector.lastElement());
    vector.removeElementAt(1);
    System.out.println("The elements of vector: " + vector); System.out.println("The size of vector is: " 
    + vector.size());
    System.out.println("The elements at position 2 is: " 
    + vector.elementAt(2));
    System.out.println("The first element of vector is: " 
    + vector.firstElement());
    System.out.println("The last element of vector is: " 
    + vector.lastElement());

    vector.clear();

    System.out.println("All numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) 
    {
        vector.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
        System.out.println(vector.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("Even Numbers: ");

    for (int i = vector.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) 
    {
        System.out.println(vector.get(i));
        if (vector.get(i) % 2 == 1);
        {
            vector.removeElementAt(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = vector.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) 
    {
        System.out.println(vector.get(i));
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Explain what the issue you have is.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to get elements at odd positions (indexes) like `a,b,c,d`->`b,d` or do you want to remove every odd number from your vector like `1,3,2,4`->`2,4`. To update your question and clarify it use [edit] option.

Comment: Are you using a non-generic list? It will assume its contents are `Object`s,  regardless of what sub-class they are, and a plain `Object` is an invalid operand for modulo.

Answer (score 0):

your Vector object should not be declared with type . this used to be the default type for early java however nowadays you may add your own type. it should, by the looks of your code be type . Therefore you know all objects in the vector are of type integer. you seem to be adding Strings and Integers in there which is not good practice.